# When does Java read method bytecode?

Tags: java, methods, jvm, bytecode, instrumentation

So during instrumentation, we noticed that when we have a method `foo` and we exchange the bytecode for it, only new invocations will operate on the new bytecode while the swap does not affect already running instances of the method.

For citing purposes, is that behaviour documented, somewhere?

Comment: Could you clarify what you meant by "instances of the method"?

Comment: and does "new invocations" mean? is it `existingInstance.foo()` or `new Instance().foo()`?

Comment: @Andrew let's say I call a method ``myinstance.foo()``, starting the first run ("instance") A. Now I concurrently exchange the bytecode for that method and call ``myinstance.foo()`` again, starting run/instance B. ``B`` will run the new bytecode while ``A`` will still run the old bytecode until it returns... or at least that is what we believe to have observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For citing purposes, is that behaviour documented, somewhere?

Yes, it is. See Javadoc for [Instrumentation.redefineClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses-java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...-):

> If a redefined method has active stack frames, those active frames continue to run the bytecodes of the original method. The redefined method will be used on new invokes.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. We're using ``ByteBuddy`` to inject our bytecode, but I'm guessing *eventually* it'll have to go through the instrumentation api.

Answer (score 0):

A distinct non-answer: it better be that way.

You see, swapping the code of a method **while** that code is running is **most likely** leading to inconsistencies.

What if your old version has 4 instructions (like 4 assignments), but the new one has 3 completely different assignments. Now 2 out of 4 assignments happens, and then code is swapped. Now what?

The whole idea of such *hot swap* activities is to **not** create inconsistent behavior. Your idea of swapping of code that is currently undergoing execution is a good recipe to exactly get to inconsistencies quickly.

Comment: The question was about where to find the documentation explaining the behavior.

Comment: @GhostCat how many non-answers do you usually provide? :) It's like the 4/5-th I encounter from you - I don't really care, just wondering

Comment: @Eugene Whenever I deem it appropriate. There are more than enough people out there trying to answer exactly what was asked, not thinking about the bigger picture. So, I consider non-answers and "the big picture" to be my niche ;-)